# Should [fieldlayoutdesigner] be renamed to [field-layout-designer]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

For readability and tradition :)

Should [fieldlayoutdesigner](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fieldlayoutdesigner) be renamed to [field-layout-designer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field-layout-designer)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Seems sensible to me, and conforms with other tag names. Let's get consensus (a few votes) and I can take care of it if we're all generally in agreement.

Comment: Works for me. :)

Comment: Maybe make it [featured] to attract more attention, there is no other questions for last month anyway :D

Comment: Words should always be separated with a `-`, improves the readability.